# SFTP set upload order by local file date

Tags: linux, bash, sftp

Reading SFTP command line shell seems there is no flag to upload entire 
folders to remote server sending local files according to the date of the last modification  so that the recently modified local files are the last to be uploaded remotely.

I tried to change the date with touch -t but sftp always seems to follow the alphabetical order.
I can not create an ordered list and send it through a batch file because my need is to send whole folders  not single file [ i.e. put  foldername ]

My need now is how to upload an entire folder that contains some XML files and only one of them having a random name that I know in advance must be sent to the remote server as last.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you create a tiny local script that internally creates a list, orders the list as you like, then opens an sftp session and uploads the entries in the list one by one before finally closing the session again?

Comment: This solution has already been screened but for the complexity and size of the lists I can not adopt it

Comment: What? What kind of list is that, that it cannot be handled by a script? What makes you think that if a single, serially approaching script cannot handle the list, that a single sftp command can?

Answer (score 0):

> My need now is how to upload an entire folder that contains some XML files and only one of them having a random name that I know in advance must be sent to the remote server as last.

- Move the one specific local file away (to a temporary folder)
- Upload the rest of the files
- Upload the specific local file explicitly
- Move the specific local file back.

Comment: This is what I am doing now :-)  but I am searching for a better solution

Comment: So please mention your existing solution in your question next time.